# Uppercase S in permissions of a folder

Tags: permissions

What does the letter `S` mean below? The file in question is a folder.

[image]

I read [here](http://permissions-calculator.org/info/) that an upper-case `S` can represent that the `setgid` bit is active for a **binary executable**. But this is a folder. Does it still mean that the `setgid` bit is activated for it? If so, what does that mean?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That means that any file dropped into the folder will take on the folder's owning group.

For example: Suppose you have a folder called "shared" which belongs to user "intrpc" and group "users", and you (as user "initrpc") drop a file into it. As a result, the file will be belong to user "intrpc" and group "users", regardless of "initrpc"'s primary group.

> On most systems, if a directory's set-group-ID bit is set, newly created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent directory.

You can read about it [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html).

Why is the letter uppercase (from the link you gave)?

> setgid has no effect if the group does not have execute permissions.
>   setgid is represented with a lower-case "s" in the output of ls. In
>   cases where it has no effect it is represented with an upper-case "S".

Comment: [Here's](http://www.toptip.ca/2010/03/linux-setgid-on-directory.html) a nice explanation of setgid applied to directories.

Comment: I think it's misleading to say `setgid has no effect if the group does not have execute permissions` because it *does* have an effect. Just add a file to the directory as the owner of the directory: the file will have the directory's group instead of the owner's primary group.

Answer (score 18):

The upper case S is because the directory does not have execute permissions for the group. In a way this indicates an "error", as you are saying:

> newly created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent directory.

(source: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html)

However, you are denying permission for the group members to enter the directory.

Answer (score 5):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#When_set_on_a_directory

> Setting the setgid permission on a directory ("chmod g+s") causes new
>   files and subdirectories created within it to inherit its group ID,
>   rather than the primary group ID of the user who created the file (the
>   owner ID is never affected, only the group ID).

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed

> ‘s’ If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit and the corresponding
>   executable bit are both set.
>
> ‘S’ If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit is set but the
>   corresponding executable bit is not set.