# File Permissions Sticky&User Execution

Tags: permissions, ls, chmod

After the website of a client has been hacked, I found some files with the following permissions set

[image]

What exactly **S** and **T** stands for?
Also, which one is the command to set them with those permissions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many information sources about the topic, but reading [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/sticky-bit-set-linux/), on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) and other similar questions asked on StackExchange like the following :

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/88391/whats-an-upper-t-at-the-end-of-unix-permissions
- https://superuser.com/questions/509114/what-does-directory-permission-s-mean-not-lower-case-but-in-upper-case
- [Uppercase S in permissions of a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27250/uppercase-s-in-permissions-of-a-folder)

we can assume that:

#### Sticky Bit

> is mainly used on folders in order to avoid deletion of a folder and
>   its content by other users though they having write permissions on the
>   folder contents. If Sticky bit is enabled on a folder, the folder
>   contents are deleted or moved by only owner who created them and the root user.

But sure, it can be done also on singular files like in your case.

#### How to set Sticky Bit

```bash
# symbolic way :
chmod +t /path/to/folder/or/file
# Numerical way :
chmod 1757 /path/to/folder/or/file
```

if you see `T` (uppercase) in the file permission area, that indicates the specific file or folder does not have executable permissions for **all** users permissions portion. Otherwise, if the sticky beat `t` is lowercase, it means the executable permission for **all** users is enabled.

#### SetGID / SetUID (set-group-ID, set-user-ID) bit

> On most systems, if a directory's set-group-ID bit is set, newly
>   created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly
>   created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent
>   directory.

Same logic for the *SetUID* bit.

#### How to SetGID / SetUID

```bash
# add the setuid bit
chmod u+s /path/to/folder/or/file
# remove the setuid bit
chmod u-s /path/to/folder/or/file
```

---

```bash
# add the setgid bit
chmod g+s /path/to/folder/or/file
# remove the setgid bit
chmod g-s /path/to/folder/or/file
```

Similar as described above, if you see `S` (uppercase) the directory's setgid bit is set, but the execute bit isn't set. is the `s` is lowercase the directory's setgid bit is set, and the execute bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the meaning of `S` and `T` on the `ls` `info` page. On systems with GNU `ls`, this should be available in the file `corutils.info.gz`, usually accessed at the shell prompt by `info ls`.  Here's an excerpt:

```
`ls' combines multiple bits into the third character of each
set of permissions as follows

. . .

`S'
    If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit is set but the
    corresponding executable bit is not set.

`T' 
    If the restricted deletion flag or sticky bit is set but the
    other-executable bit is not set.
```

The command usually used to set these bits is `chmod`, and any binary command or program can call the kernel system call `chmod` to accomplish the same things.

See these man pages for more information:

```
man 1 chmod
man 2 chmod
```